# Problems finding ruby, rails, git after bungled PostgreSQL install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, rvm

I had rails working fine for several weeks but I tried to install PostgreSQL to match Heroku and it failed to work. Now, when I open the terminal it pretend rails is not there and sets the default ruby to 1.8.7. When I start RVM it finds the right version of ruby and finds rails again and can start the server but each time I open a new shell it's back to not finding anything. Plus, the git commands don't work even after starting rvm.

I have set rvm to start by default but that doesn't work either, it has to be started manually, and it still doesn't fix the git issue.

More Detail

I am installing on Mountain Lion. This already has Postgres but the tutorial I was using suggested installing fresh using Homebrew. The trouble was the Homebrew installation installs to /usr/local/var/postgres and the installed ppstgres installs to usr/var/postgres. The system automatically uses the usr/var/postgres version, so following the tutorial I chnaged the order of usr/local/bin and usr/bin in etc/paths. That didn't help so I changed it back. Everything then went to hell so I reinstalled Mountain Lion but nothing had changed.

Comment: I have to say a PostgreSQL installation by itself could not have done all that unless a serious malfunction of a package manager happened. You should add more information of the operative system and how did you try to install PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

There are two known problems with loading RVM & default ruby:

1. login shell: go to terminal emulator preferences and enable login shell, sometimes it might be required to use `/bin/bash --login` instead.
2. ZSH (+ Oh-My-ZSH): go to `~/.zshrc` and comment out any lines starting with: `PATH=` or `path=(`, it is still possible to use those but they need to reference itself like: `PATH=$PATH:HOME/.rvm/bin` or `path+=( $HOME/.rvm/bin )` - which update and not reset `PATH`. This might be a bug in terminal emulator or ZSH ...

Answer (score 0):

The git issue is explained by the reinstall of Mountain Lion which did not automatically install the command line tools. That now works. The only pain is having to load rvm every time now.